# ID this set: Rocket launch installation?

Tags: set-identification

While cleaning out the attic of my deceased cousin I found a plastic bag with parts that supposedly is a single set from late 70 or early 80's.

Actually there where multiple bags, each containing a single set. Some had the instructions leaflet and others I could relatively easily identify. They all date from around 1980. So that is why I presume that the one bag left is also a single set from that period.

Sorry that I don't have pictures. I may add one later.

- A large green ground-plate (about 40x30 nobs, I didn't count them exactly) with white printed markings where the first layer of bricks should go.
- 2 pieces of straight blue railroad track.
- Regular bricks mostly 1x1x4 and 1x1x8 in blue.
- A bunch of white quarter-circle bricks and some (4) black ones + a white nose-cone piece. Would together make a small white rocket with a black band or black markings. A bit Saturn-V like.

It looks as if this would make a rocket + a base or launch-tower. The tracks are maybe part of a moveable launch-pad? There are no wheels to go with the track though.

Does this ring a bell for someone?

Comment: I think you probably have parts to multiple sets. I picture would help to identify them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Minus the reference to the large green baseplate, could it be pieces from *[Set #358 - Rocket Base](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=358-1)?*

**Edit**:
A few original, used red baseplates can be easily had under $10 bucks through a few Canadian sellers ***[HERE](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=10p03&idColor=5#T=S&C=5&O=%7B%22color%22:5,%22reg%22:%223%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D)***.

[image]

Comment: That looks like it, but the base-plate is most certainly green. Not red. It does have markings for the outline of the buildings and those 3 tiles in front of the "office". The antenna's, the black turn-table for the radar, the pieces for the vehicle all match.

Comment: The green base plate is just from a different set, even though your Cuzo had it bagged with these pieces.  Sorry for your loss.  You say the plate has lines on it.  We prefer a picture, or you can describe further in detail with words the white line work on it.  For all we know, your cousin may had time to do a custom paint job on it.  A picture would quickly determine that..

Comment: You were right. The green base-plate isn't original. I just got of the phone with his brother. He remembered the red plate broke at some point and he bought a generic green base-plate (slightly larger as well) as replacement. Back in the day the better toy-stores sold a limited selection of spare bricks including grey and green base plates. He did the painting himself with Tipp-Ex.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up regarding getting a proper replacement base-plate. I've got a replacement on order now :-)

Answer (score 3):

The closest I can find is [358 Rocket Base](https://brickset.com/sets/358-1/Rocket-Base), but it contains more pieces than you describe and the baseplate is red not green.

Comment: I didn't describe all pieces. Just the more prominent ones.